# List All posts under its own category title WP Query

Tags: wordpress

Hi Hope You All doing well, I implemented a search for posts that are connected to categories child and then the parent of that child everything works perfect in search but I want to bring the search post under its own category and not to repeat that category title again and again for the post title here is my code script and check screenshot here what I mean to say
screenshot before search https://prnt.sc/10kzkvp
screenshot after search https://prnt.sc/10kzmxt  As you can see here I want to list posts inside its own category and not repeat the category title for its post, let me know if need more explanation

```
<?php
      $args =  array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'extend_where' => "(post_title like '%$s_word%')",
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby'=> 'title', 
      'order' => 'ASC'
      );

       // The Query
       $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
       // The Loop
       if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $icon_flag = false;
            $child_c = "";
            $parent_c = "";
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $the_query->the_post();
                     $split_title = explode(',', get_the_title(), 2);
                     $id = get_the_ID();
                     $current_cate =  get_the_terms($id,'category');
                     $parent = $current_cate[0]->parent;
                     //load object for parent category
                     $parent_name = get_the_category_by_ID($parent);
                    if($parent_name != $parent_c && $parent != 0)
                    {
                    $parent_c = $parent_name;
                    ?>
                    <h1 class="grand-p-title p-parent"><?php echo $parent_c; ?></h1>
                    <?php 
                        }
                        if($current_cate[0]->name != $child_c )
                        {
                        $child_c = $current_cate[0]->name;
                         ?>
                <!-- <h1 class="grand-p-title p-child"><?php //echo $current_cate[0]->name; ?></h1> -->
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            <p class="post-letters"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><span class="first-w"><?php echo $split_title[0].", ";?></span><?php echo $split_title[1]; ?></a></p>
            <?php
               } 
           }else
           {
            ?>
        <p class="post-letters"><a>No posts founds</a></p> 
        <?php
        }
        wp_reset_query();  
        ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are doing wrong. you need to loop of categories first and then based on the category you have to get posts. for fetch all categories you can use WP [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( array (
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => false
) );

// run a query for each term
foreach( $terms as $term ) {

    // Define the query
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'cat'            => $term->term_id,
        'extend_where'   => "(post_title like '%$s_word%')",
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'title', 
        'order'          => 'ASC'
    );

    // run the query 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 

        $icon_flag = false;
        $child_c   = "";
        $parent_c  = "";
        
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

            $split_title  = explode(',', get_the_title(), 2);
            $id           = get_the_ID();
            $current_cate =  get_the_terms($id,'category');
            $parent       = $current_cate[0]->parent;
            
            //load object for parent category
            $parent_name = get_the_category_by_ID($parent);
            
            if($parent_name != $parent_c && $parent != 0) {
                $parent_c = $parent_name; ?>
                <h1 class="grand-p-title p-parent"><?php echo $parent_c; ?></h1>
            <?php  }

            if($current_cate[0]->name != $child_c ) {
                $child_c = $current_cate[0]->name; ?>
                <!-- <h1 class="grand-p-title p-child"><?php //echo $current_cate[0]->name; ?></h1> -->
            <?php } ?>
            <p class="post-letters"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="first-w"><?php echo $split_title[0].", ";?></span><?php echo $split_title[1]; ?></a></p>

        <?php } 

    }else { ?>

        <p class="post-letters"><a>No posts founds</a></p> 

    <?php } wp_reset_query();  
}
```